# How to implement Role-based REST API

Tags: rest, symfony, model-view-controller, frameworks, roles

I have two different roles in my project: `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.
I want to get list of all users through *REST API's* url `'/users'`, but some fields (for example `email`) can see only those person, who authenticated with `ROLE_ADMIN`.
So, I have generally 2 questions:

1) *On which abstraction level (in `MVC` pattern) should I decide which information can be returned based on `ROLE`*
2) *Which is the best way to implement such a Role-based REST API in Symfony?*

---

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `JMSSerializer` you can use groups to decide what can be seen or not. Then in your controller, or where ever, you could set the group based on the role.

For example with the mapping (in YAML)..

```
Fully\Qualified\Class\Name:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            groups: [user]
        userAndAdmin:
            groups: [user]
        adminOnly:
            groups: [admin]
```

And then in your controller you would set the group like...

```
public function getUsersAction(Request $request)
{
    $users = $this->getRepository()->findAll();
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer.serializer');

    $json = $serializer->serialize(
        $users,
        'json',
        SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($this->generateGroups())
    );

    return new Response($json);

    // If you are using FOSRestBundle, which I would recommend, then you would just need to do...
    $view = $this
        ->view($this->getRepository()->findAll();)
        ->setExclusionGroups($this->generateGroups())
    ;

    return $this->handleView($view);
}

private function generateGroups()
{
    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
    $groups = array();

    if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        $groups[] = 'user';
    }

    if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        $groups[] = 'admin';
    }

    return $groups;
}
```

Although the whole "generateGroups" and setting the groups would be better placed in a customer view handler or response generator.

Assuming your hierarchy has `ROLE_ADMIN` as a parent of `ROLE_USER` you would get the following results.

<kbd>ROLE_USER</kbd>

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "userAndAdmin": "val"
        }
    ]
}
```

<kbd>ROLE_ADMIN</kbd>

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "userAndAdmin": "val",
            "adminOnly": "val"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's great! More over I can use it with annotations, and it will be simple as a few lines of code. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Since the API is dependent on user who is making the request, each request will have to carry the information about the current user. Usually all authorization related tasks are processed within the controller. So, answer to your first question is that you should process the roles in the controller and based on the roles, you should  filter out the fields from the data returned from the repository. For example,

```
//users is the array of user objects returned by your repository

data = [];

if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
  foreach($users as $user){
  // Add ROLE_ADMIN specific data
        data[][] = array(
            'name' => $user->getName(),
            'email' => $user->getEmail(),
        );
  }     
}


if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
   foreach($users as $user){
    // Add ROLE_USER specific data
    data[][] = array(
        'name' => $user->getName(),
        'address' => $user->getAddress(),
               );
   } 

  }
```

then, JSON encode the data array and return as the response. To reduce the number of queries, you can add a __toArray method in your User class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it seems to me that it's toooo cumbersome to do so. The code in controller will be large and hardly maintanable.