# REST API response depending on who made the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, permissions, user-roles, clean-architecture

I'm working on a Public && Private REST API and I would like to ask something regarding non/logged users.

We're using the following gem to [Serialize](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) each object.

Case A:

My public part of my website shows some book details. My endpoint is GET /api/books/{book_id}. Let's say book_id is 1.
For non logged users, the response is the following one:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone"
}
```

For logged users, I want something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Harry Potter and the philosopher's stone",
  author: "J. K. Rowling"
}
```

As you can notice, author details are just for logged users (I don't care about the user role).

Case B:

Depending on user roles.

Let's say I want to query some user information through GET /api/users/{user_id}. Let's say user_id is 1 as well.

As a logged user and non-admin user, I'll receive this as a response:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "John"
}
```

But as an admin, I would like to receive:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "John",
 address: "9th street in the East Village, Manhattan"
}
```

As non logged user, it should return a 401 error. Not authorized.

Notice in this example, address info is just for admin users.

I'm wondering If this logic should be in two different endpoints, or in the same endpoint. I don't want to use any query params in the same URL.

For me is really confusing to have one endpoint with multiple returns depending on the person who makes that request. I have seen some articles talking about rol-based REST API, but seems that sometimes is not really clear and is really up to you.

Also, my doubts are related to a POST request. Is really confusing to know which parameter will receive. I'm thinking if you have 6/7 roles, and you need to have different results depending on some business logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999790/how-to-implement-role-based-rest-api - Have a read through this :)

Comment: That's cool for MVC and for Java, but it's not really my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `if` you can pass to `attribute` method:

Case A:

```rb
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id
  attribute :name
  attribute :author, if: :user_signed_in?

  def user_signed_in?
    scope.present?
  end
end
```

Case B:

```rb
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :id
  attribute :name
  attribute :address, if: -> { scope.admin? }
end
```

See details in the [official documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md).

Personally I would rather use one endpoint for both cases, because it's simpler solution without code duplication.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That was my plan B. I knew these features for the Serializer, but I believe is not really "clean" write some business logic in the Serializer. In the end, serializers are just to convert data to JSON, from my point of view it shouldn't have any logic. That's why I opened this discussion.

Comment: @rails95 I don't think this is business logic in serializer. In case A we add a method `user_signed_in?` which is a piece of *application* logic and in case B we just use business logic that comes with `User` model.